# Does realloc actually shrink buffers in common implementations?

Tags: python, c, memory-management, numpy, malloc

In common implementations such as Linux/Glibc, Windows/MSVC and BSD/Mac OS X, will

```
void *p = malloc(N + M);  // assume this doesn't fail
p = realloc(p, N);        // nor this
```

for `N`, `M > 0`, actually shrink the buffer returned by `malloc` in the `realloc` call, in the sense that up to `M` bytes may return to the free list? And more importantly, is there a chance that it reallocates the buffer?

I want to know because I just implemented dynamic arrays on top of `numpy.ndarray`, and I'm doing a `resize`, which calls `realloc`, to get the final size right. I may be able to skip the final `resize` as an optimization (at the expense of permanent overallocation) and I want to know if that's even worth trying.

Comment: @jterrace how would you test that the internal implementation shrunk the size of the memory you own?

Comment: On some implementations the memory isn't even allocated when you call `malloc` or `realloc`...

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the value of the pointer actually changes. Compare the values of `p` before and after. If it does change then you know *something*'s going on.

Comment: I meant testing by comparing the performance when resizing and not resizing, to see if the optimization is "worth it".

Comment: @Joe: I'm aware that some OSs don't set aside a physical page for freshly allocated virtual memory immediately. But IMHO it's a strecth to call that "not allocated".

Comment: @Joe: ok, that would test the actual allocation. But I expect testing whether any memory is returned to the free list would be hard if it isn't.

Comment: @Joe yes, but also remember that if it doesn't change, you _don't_ know something's _not_ going on.

Comment: @jterrace: ah, ok. No, I didn't try yet. I was hoping someone here would be familiar with `malloc` internals so I could know in advance what I was testing.

Comment: You cannot assume that `realloc()` in this case won't reallocate the buffer. One reason is that `realloc()` may choose to do so is in order to minimize fragmentation. There's implementation dependent. It would be best to look in the official interface documentation of `realloc()` on those platforms. In order to achieve maximum portability it's advised not to assume anything beyond what the documentation provides "by contract".

Comment: @SethCarnegie absolutely, yes. It was more a comment that you can't really say what's going on without reading the source code of the libc in question. Let alone what happens in the MMU.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can say about Linux/glibc.
In the source code it contains comments like this:

> if `n` is for fewer bytes than already held by `p`, the newly unused
>    space is lopped off and freed if possible.

if you look at code of glibc, it contains lines like this:

```
remainder_size = newsize - nb;

if (remainder_size < MINSIZE) { /* not enough extra to split off */
  set_head_size(newp, newsize | (av != &main_arena ? NON_MAIN_ARENA : 0));
  set_inuse_bit_at_offset(newp, newsize);
}
else { /* split remainder */
  remainder = chunk_at_offset(newp, nb);
  set_head_size(newp, nb | (av != &main_arena ? NON_MAIN_ARENA : 0));
  set_head(remainder, remainder_size | PREV_INUSE |
       (av != &main_arena ? NON_MAIN_ARENA : 0));
  /* Mark remainder as inuse so free() won't complain */
  set_inuse_bit_at_offset(remainder, remainder_size);
 #ifdef ATOMIC_FASTBINS
  _int_free(av, remainder, 1);
 #else
  _int_free(av, remainder);
 #endif
}
```

`nb` - number of bytes you want, `newsize` here, should be called `oldsize`.
So it tries to free the excess if possible.

About Mac OSX. More precisely about `magazine_malloc`, current implementation of `malloc` from Apple. See http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/look-at-how-malloc-works-on-mac.html for details.

`realloc` calls the zone realloc method, its current implementation as I see is `szone_realloc`.
For different allocation sizes exists different code, but the algorithm is always the same:

```
if (new_good_size <= (old_size >> 1)) {
            /*
             * Serious shrinkage (more than half). free() the excess.
             */
            return tiny_try_shrink_in_place(szone, ptr, old_size, new_good_size);
} else if (new_good_size <= old_size) {
            /* 
             * new_good_size smaller than old_size but not by much (less than half).
             * Avoid thrashing at the expense of some wasted storage.
             */
             return ptr;
}
```

So as you can see, its implementation checks that `new_size <= old_size / 2`, and if so frees memory, and if not it does nothing.

Comment: what is `main_arena`?

Comment: @jrwren you can look at source code of glibc https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/ and find out answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not its worth it depends on how long the object is going to be around and how important it is to the application to reduce its memory footprint. There's no one right generic answer.

Generic memory allocators typically assume that the caller knows the previous size of the block and would only be called `realloc` if they actually knew they wanted to shrink the block. The last one I looked at was willing to shrink the block if the block was already over 128 bytes and the reallocation would free at least 1KB or at least a number of bytes equal to 1/4 of the block's current allocation size. It was tuned for high-volume server applications where objects typically don't stay around very long and where a special 'right size' operation was offered for objects known to be around for very long periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. But standard says nothing that forces that. So you have to check it with the `libc` you are targeting. You can do that either by looking at the code, if available, or by writing a test program. The idea for the test program is this - you allocate relatively large block (say 10K), then try to shrink like a half with `realloc` and allocate something small with `malloc`. If newly returned address lays in the range you have allocated for the first time then your `realloc` shrinks, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: If newly returned address lays in the range you have allocated for the first time then your realloc shrinks, otherwise it *may or may not*.  There might be reasons for the second `malloc` to allocate somewhere other than the previously shrunk region, even if it's available.